# Qt new - multiple instances or a pointer to the single one

Tags: c++, instance, new-operator

I need a confirmation if Im right or not. I've created a QSlider and a plot with a cos function. The Slider is connected to a slot_print(int). The aim is to move the function. I've accomplished it in two different ways:

```
//---the first way
void plot::slot_print(int a){
  cosinusdata->setData(a);
  **curve->setData(cosinusdata);**
  this->replot();
};


//the second way
void plot::slot_print(int a){
    **curve->setData(new CosinusData(a));**
    this->replot();
};

//the CosinusData class
class CosinusData: public QwtSyntheticPointData{
public:
    int b;
    CosinusData(int a):QwtSyntheticPointData(1000){b=a;}
    double y(double x) const {return b*qCos(x);}
    void setData(int a){b=a;}
};

// constructor
plot::plot()
{
setAxisScale(QwtPlot::xBottom,-3.0,12.5,2);
setAxisScale(QwtPlot::yLeft,-3.0,14.5,3);
curve = new QwtPlotCurve();
**cosinusdata = new CosinusData(1);**
curve->setData(cosinusdata);
curve->attach(this);
}
```

I Don't want to make multiple instance of the CosinusData class. I want only one so I guess the first way does the job. Am I right or not ? Is that true that the second one creates a new instance every time a signal is accepted?

Answer (score 0):

> Is that true that the second one creates a new instance every time a signal is accepted?

Yes.

In the second way, you are dynamically allocating memory with each call. Unless "curve->setData" takes ownership of CosinusData, that it doesn't delete it after being finished with it you are leaking memory!

Probably the fastest fix would be to wrap CosinusData you are passing with QSharedPointer, but if you can it is better to avoid dynamic allocation and deallocation for each call.

I cannot safely say about first solution, because I don't see other parts of code (part of ownership of pointer). From the pointer point of view it seems ok. But since you are doing copying and passing twice (first to cosinusdata, then to curve) make sure there are no expensive operations here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer !